# How to create a link to an Opportunity that does not specify lightning/non lightning?

Tags: api, weblinks

I need to create a link to an Opportunity. I get the Opportunity ID from the (REST) API.

I see regular links are

```
https://na85.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Opportunity/xxxxxxxxxxx/view
```

But not sure if the user is using lightning or classic.

How to create a link that does not change between lightining or classic?

Comment: Have you tried `https://na85.lightning.force.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A link that will work in any environment is

```
https://<base domain name>/<Salesforce id>
```

You can use as your base domain name either your `*.lightning.force.com` or your Classic domain name (`mycompany.my.salesforce.com` or `na85.salesforce.com`).

Salesforce will redirect the user to the appropriate URL for their logged-in experience. Users who are on the Lightning experience will see their browsers redirect through a URL including `/_classic/` and then end up at the `/r/sObjectName/sObjectId/view` URL.

Comment: +1 `https://login.salesforce.com/<id>` or `https://test.salesforce.com/<id>`  also automatically redirects them if already logged in to the appropriate location. If they have multiple saved logins, they can choose which one to use.

Comment: Is there any documentation for this?

Comment: @BSeven According to [this Developer Blog post](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/01/heres-need-know-new-url-format-lightning.html), Salesforce does not consider URLs to be part of an API and they are not officially supported/documented.